# How can we convert below normal query to Laravel DB or Elequent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying the get the records that are in between the start and end date based on the current date. I have normal SQL working query and now I am trying it to convert into eloquent query, but I am failing somewhere. Please help me for for this.

BASIC QUERY:

`SELECT startDate, endDate
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE '2012-10-25' between startDate and endDate`

What I had tried:

```
$q = RoundTable::select(['round_start_date','round_end_date'])->whereBetween('2019-10-25', ['round_start_date', 'round_end_date'])->get();
```

I got an error as

```
  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2019-10-25' in 'where clause' (SQL: select ` 
   round_start_date`, `round_end_date` from `round_table` where `2019-10-25` between round_start_date 
   and round_end_date`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change query to :

```
$q = RoundTable::select(['round_start_date','round_end_date'])
->whereRaw('? between round_start_date and round_end_date', ['2019-10-25'])
->get();
```